# How to call new class with global scope from function

Tags: vb.net, class

Salvete!  I want to create a new instance of a class when I click on a button, but I need to interact with members of that class using other controls on the form, so I need the class to have a global scope.  I know I could call the new class in formload, but the class creates certain variables that need to be current.  If it is done on formload, the variables wouldn't be current, because if the class is created at formload, it would have different info at that time.  Surely, there must be a way to create an instance of the myClass from within a sub that is accessible from other subs of the same class.

Something like this:
  click on `myForm.button1` to `dim myclassInstance as new myClass`

then, click on `myForm.button2`, to make `mylabel.text = myClassiInstance.myvariable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may be having problems because MyClass is a reserved keyword, so if you are trying to create a class with this name, you will need to choose a different class name.

Having said that, I believe that what you want is something similar to the following, where we store the instance of the class as a private member of the form. This instance will only "live" as long as the form exists, so if it needs to be share among forms, then you will need to move the instance to a different location (a global variable or a shared member).

```
Public Class Form1

    Private m_CurrentInstance As ThisIsMyClass

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        m_CurrentInstance = New ThisIsMyClass
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If m_CurrentInstance IsNot Nothing Then
            myLabel.Text = m_CurrentInstance.MyVariable
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I just used "MyClass" as an example; I didn't realize it was reserved.  Anyway, that did it!  It was just what I needed.  I'm marking this as accepted.  Thanks!  (and thanks for fixing the style display for my question!)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what you are asking for but it seems like you just want to check out the Shared keyword. Basically Shared means single instance.

So whatever you apply it to will be created only once and be tied to the type of the class not an instance of it.

```
 Private Shared sharedInt As Integer
    Private Shared sharedPropValue As String
```

[How to create and use shared members by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308371)

Comment: Maybe I should just take the "Public Sub New()" out of my class?  I am a bit new to OOP, and am still confused in some places.  But I don't use the class except in a few places, and I don't see why I would need to change its parameters for a new instance anyway.  Then, when I call the function inside the class, it would be fresh info.  Then I could make the class a public property in my form class?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, I tried removing "Public Sub New()", and it compiles, but when I try to access the class, it tells me to create a new instance anyway.